# Cordova - Prevent back button from closing app on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been struggling with this issue where in my cordova app, the back button will exit the app no matter what. I have tried all the solutions I've come across online but haven't had any success.

All the solutions I've tried (example below) have produced the same result.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

The code inside my callback executes without issue, but after it executes, it exits the app. I can prevent the exit by including a ReferenceError in my function, for example

```
console.log(undefinedVar);
```

But this obviously doesn't seem like best practice.
Is there a solution?

Comment: can you try this `document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, as any other solution i found online

Comment: i guess you add the back button event listener after the device ready event has fired, or else it will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please try below code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: The method is being called but the app closes before the instruction is executed, so the app still closes on back button press

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 6 years. But I think you are referring to a line of code generated by the plugin [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) which causes the app to crash when you press the hardware back button.

File is located at:

```
/path_to_your_project/android/app/src/main/assets/public/plugins/cordova-plugin-background-mode/www/background-mode.js
```

```
exports.overrideBackButton = function()
{
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {
        exports.moveToBackground();
    }, false);
};
```

Replace the line `exports.moveToBackground();` with something else... like an empty `console.log()`.

You'd have to do this manually everytime after those files are reloaded, so I've made a simple automation script in bash (put it in `/path_of_your_project/` folder):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

file=./android/app/src/main/assets/public/plugins/cordova-plugin-background-mode/www/background-mode.js

sed -i 's/exports.moveToBackground();/console.log("back button event from cordova-plugin-background-mode")/' $file

exit 0
```